# Calculate 30 Day retention rate for new customers acquired each day

Tags: sql, pandas, google-bigquery

```
I have a database of Transaction Data containing these columns

PK_Order_nr   PK_Order_item_number     Amount     Purchase_date      Customer_ID
   20045              12365              20        2021-08-08             5564
   20045              12789              50        2021-08-08             5564
   20045              14789              44        2021-08-08             5564
   20046              19635              63        2021-08-09             7854
   20047              77895              78        2021-08-10             3699
   20047              78456              78        2021-08-10             3699
```

Each order number can have multiple items, I want to do a 30-day retention rate analysis on customers and find out the retention rate of new customers acquired each day.

The result which I want to achieve after the analysis is done, Thanks for help and suggestions.

[image]

```
    with fo as (
    select 
    fk_customer,
    created_at,
    LEAD(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY fk_customer ORDER BY created_at) as next_order_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_customer ORDER BY created_at) as seqnum
    from `xxx-xxx.sales_order`
    WHERE Extract(date from created_at) >= '2019-01-04'
)

select * from fo 
where Extract(date from created_at) = '2019-01-04'
and seqnum =  1
and DATE_DIFF(created_at, next_order_date, day) <= 30
```

Played around with the LEAD function couldn't get what I expected

Comment: How to identify "new customers acquired each day."? OR How to identify "new customers"?

Comment: So the customers who placed their first order that day, or the unique customer ids who made the first purchase on that particular date, I have the data Since 1st Jan 2017.

Comment: So the cohort for each day will consist of the unique customers who placed orders that day , for whom we will calculate the retention rate for First Day + 30 days , First day excluded

Comment: Ok, then what's definition of customers who transacted in 30 day window?

Comment: The customers who placed orders may be one, maybe more in the 30 day period after placing the first order, so if a customer x places and orders today, he is born today, counting 30 days after that how many orders has the customer placed

Comment: If I understand, a new customer is the customer who bought 1st time in the current month, and if that customer will buy another time it will be a regular customer? Will this customer be a `new customer` if he will buy something on 1st of Jan and then if he will buy again on 1st of Feb will be counted as a new customer? You added a panda tag, you are using `Panda` or `GBQ Panda`? What is your current result if you will use your code?